# SSL access from inside of docker container always failed

Tags: git, docker, ssl

I am trying to clone a github repos but it always failed. The message looks like this:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/dotnet/reactive.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: none CRLfile: none
```

I noticed that it seems there is something from with SSL certificate when I am inside the docker container. Anyway to fix this?

I am running Docker Desktop for Mac (M1 chip) version 4.12.0 and engine version v20.10.17.

I have tried to set the SSL verification for git to false and it is working but when I am doing another thing, like composer install something, it always fail with SSL certificate.

I hope I can fix the root cause of the issue with the SSL certificate instead of bypassing it. I don't think I have this isse when I am using Docker in Linux.

Comment: What SSL certificates have you provided via your Docker container? Compare the ones you provide on your Linux docker setup to the ones you provide on your Mac-M1 setup.

Comment: I suspect this is the cause but don't know how to check it. Can you give me the way to check it?

Comment: Look at your Docker setup (Dockerfile or other method of bringing the Docker system up) and/or get the thing started and then log into it and poke around while it runs.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely possibility is that you haven't installed the CA certificates inside of the Docker container.  In Debian and Ubuntu, those are in the `ca-certificates` package.  If you install that, then Git and everything else on the system will find them, and you won't need to override the TLS verification (which is a security risk).

Comment: I have checked this also and the ca-certificate package is already installed.

Comment: Then it might be that you have some sort of MITM software or device on the Mac that's tampering with certificates.  Any sort of nonstandard firewall or antivirus, as well as certain monitoring software, can do that.

Comment: this is my company laptop and it definitely has company setting that I don't know.

Comment: Okay, well, that's your problem.  Remove the MITM software and things will work.